# "Animated node with ID 2 Already exists" and "Unrecognized operator min" errors (Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I get the following error when I have react-native-reanimated installed:

```
Animated node with ID 2 Already exists
```

And this error when I remove it:

```
Unrecognized Operator min
```

- The online solutions to fix the first problem conclude that react-native-reanimated should be **removed**
- The online solutions to fix the second problem conclude that react-native-reanimate should be **installed**

How can I fix both?

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock && yarn install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "expo": "^38.0.9",
    "expo-mail-composer": "^8.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.3.1",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "lottie-react-native": "~2.6.1",
    "material-colors": "^1.2.6",
    "native-base": "^2.13.13",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "react-native-cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.4",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-skeleton-content": "^1.0.18",
    "react-native-web": "^0.13.4",
    "react-native-webview": "9.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "typescript-eslint": "^0.0.1-alpha.0",
    "valid-url": "^1.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint": "7.4.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.0.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody stumbles onto this issue, I solved it by:

1. creating a new project
2. moving all the files to this project (except for `package.json`)
3. installing all the needed dependencies 1 by 1

PS. I haven't tested it, but you might be able to do it by removing **all** dependencies in `package.json` and installing them one by one without creating a whole new project.

Answer (score 2):

in my case this happened when i installed the package react-native-floating-label-input, all i did was uninstall the package, deleted node modules then ran `npm i`  and i was good to go